# Please help me with a tabular problem

Tags: tables

[image]

The above table is from [C. Bonatto and E. Bica: Fundamental parameters of M 52 and NGC 3960](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0608022v1.pdf)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{small}
%\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\begin{table}[htp]
%\restylefloat{table}
 \centering\small\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

%\centering \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5pt}
%\toprule
\hspace*{0cm}\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{3pt}} *{15}{c}}

%\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1pt}} *{12}{c}}
\hline
\hline

%\bfseries cluster&
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries previous study}&
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries present study}\\

         \hline
clusters & $RA_{J2000}$ &$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ & $\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d&$RA_{J2000}$&$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ &$\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d\\
          &        &(hms)&(dms)& (arcmin)&(arcmin)&(year)&(mag)&(Kpc)&(hms)&(dms)&(arcmin)&(arcmin)& (year)&(mag)&(Kpc)\\
         \hline
\bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$
         &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
\hline
\hline
%\toprule
\end{tabular}\hspace*{0cm}
\caption{astrophysical parameters obtained from ischrone fitting}\label{tab:comber}
%\end{sidewaystable}
\end{table}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want table like in the picture.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. It's great that you provide a code example, but it wouldn't hurt to state the problem in words as well. One suggestion would be to reorganize the table, with *present study* below *previous study*, that would reduce the width of the table.

Comment: Is there a question? By the way, there is no `small` environment that I know of.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use a landscape page to display the tabular.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hi,http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbjorn-t thank you so math. but I need two studies.

Comment: I'm not saying remove one of the studies, I'm saying put the two studies in two separate rows ...

Comment: yes I Know http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbjorn-t.but I have 5 clusters more.

Comment: Well given that you want it to fit on A4, how do you want to arrange it? If you have further clusters, that seems an even stronger reason to go with @TorbjørnT.'s suggestion since even if you somehow squeeze the existing table in (perhaps in landscape orientation), you won't have that option once you add further to the width.

Comment: pleas@cfr look for my Picture.

Comment: The fact that is letter paper helps a bit. So does the fact that many of the columns contain less width of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to put it into landscape, but the following will at least make it fit on a page.  (BTW, it is also too big for landscape.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphics}% for \resizebox

\begin{document}

%\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\begin{table}[htp]
%\restylefloat{table}
 \centering\small\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

%\centering \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5pt}
%\toprule
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% fit on page
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{3pt}} *{15}{c}}

%\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1pt}} *{12}{c}}
\hline
\hline

%\bfseries cluster&
& \multicolumn{7}{l}{\parbox{5in}%
  {\centering\textbf{previous study}\\
  \rule[.6\baselineskip]{5in}{.5pt}}}
& \multicolumn{7}{l}{\parbox{5in}%
  {\centering\textbf{present study}\\
  \rule[.6\baselineskip]{5in}{.5pt}}}
\vspace{-5pt}\\
clusters & $RA_{J2000}$ &$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ & $\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d&$RA_{J2000}$&$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ &$\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d\\
          &        &(hms)&(dms)& (arcmin)&(arcmin)&(year)&(mag)&(Kpc)&(hms)&(dms)&(arcmin)&(arcmin)& (year)&(mag)&(Kpc)\\
\hline
\bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$
     &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
\hline
\hline
%\toprule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{astrophysical parameters obtained from ischrone fitting}\label{tab:comber}
%\end{sidewaystable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Actually, I like Jesse's solution better.  I just couldn't remember \cline at the time.

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible solution where labels (1) to (15) are added for clearance. This solution thinks cfr and torbjorn fellow users are giving the right direction and furthermore, the gap (shown by (A),B,C here) between the two study categories is given troubles. There are a total of 16 columns and the `multicolumn` grouping is a source of error too.

Note: removing (A),B,C will give the right gap. Here they serve as beacons for reference.

[image]

Code

```
\begin{document}

%\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\begin{table}[!htp]
%\restylefloat{table}
 \centering\small\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

%\centering \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5pt}
%\toprule
\hspace*{0cm}
\caption{astrophysical parameters obtained from ischrone fitting}\label{tab:comber}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{3pt}} *{15}{c}}
%\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1pt}} *{12}{c}}
\hline
\hline
%\bfseries cluster
&
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\bfseries Previous study}&&
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\bfseries Present study}\\
\cline{2-8}\cline{10-16}
clusters & $RA_{J2000}$ &$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ & $\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d&&$RA_{J2000}$&$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ &$\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d\\
        &(hms)&(dms)& (arcmin)&(arcmin)&(year)&(mag)&(Kpc)&&(hms)&(dms)&(arcmin)&(arcmin)& (year)&(mag)&(Kpc)\\
(1)&(2)&(3)&(4)&(5)&(6)&(7)&(8)&(A) &(9)&(10)&(11)&(12)&(13)&(14)&(15)\\
         \hline
\bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$ &$+51 02.8$ & $2.5\pm0.1$    &$\simeq 20$ &$9.09\pm0.02$  &$1.52\pm0.01$ &$3.1\pm0.1$&B
         &                  &                  & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$ &$3240\pm440$\\
         \hline
\bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$         &C
         &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
\hline
\hline
%\toprule
\end{tabular}\hspace*{0cm}
%\end{sidewaystable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Squeezed tabular]

You could do this. I don't recommend it, but it is possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hscale=.925]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

 \centering\scriptsize\setlength\tabcolsep{.25pt}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{l*{15}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries previous study} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries present study}\\\midrule
clusters & $RA_{J2000}$ &$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ & $\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d&$RA_{J2000}$&$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ &$\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d\\
          &        &(hms)&(dms)& (arcmin)&(arcmin)&(year)&(mag)&(Kpc)&(hms)&(dms)&(arcmin)&(arcmin)& (year)&(mag)&(Kpc)\\\midrule
\bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$
         &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{astrophysical parameters obtained from ischrone fitting}\label{tab:comber}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```