# Help me Please. table size by latex

Tags: tables, paper-size

[image]

image 1 is very small and font size also small . how can I make like next image

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{graphics}% for \resizebox

\begin{table}[htp]
%\restylefloat{table}
 \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}
 \small

%\centering \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5pt}
%\toprule
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% fit on page
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{3.5pt}} *{15}{c}}

%\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1pt}} *{12}{c}}
\hline
\hline

%\bfseries cluster&
& \multicolumn{7}{l}{\parbox{5in}%
  {\centering\textbf{previous study}\\
  \rule[.6\baselineskip]{5in}{.5pt}}}
& \multicolumn{7}{l}{\parbox{5in}%
  {\centering\textbf{present study}\\
  \rule[.6\baselineskip]{5in}{.5pt}}}
\vspace{-1pt}\\
clusters & $RA_{J2000}$ &$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ & $\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d&$RA_{J2000}$&$DEc_{J2000}$& $r_{core}$& $r_{lim}$ &$\log(age)$&E$(B-V)$&d\\
                  &(hms)&(dms)& (arcmin)&(arcmin)&(year)&(mag)&(Kpc)&(hms)&(dms)&(arcmin)&(arcmin)& (year)&(mag)&(Kpc)\\
\hline
\bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$
     &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
     \bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$
     &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
     \bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$
     &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
     \bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$
     &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
     \bfseries Berkeley 53
         &$20 55 56$&$+51 02.8$& $2.5\pm0.1$&$\simeq 20$&$9.09\pm0.02$&$1.52\pm0.01$&$3.1\pm0.1$
     &              &               & $4.19\pm0.28$ &$20\pm1.6$ &$9.10\pm0.05$  &$1.39\pm0.42$&$3240\pm440$\\
\hline
\hline
%\toprule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{astrophysical parameters obtained from ischrone fitting}\label{tab:comber}
%\end{sidewaystable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` you'll see, that the table fills the whole width of the text area (as you told latex with your `\resizebox`). The font is scaled accordingly as `\resizebox` only scales the whole box. Besides, the table is rather full, so you couldn't even save space inside the table. The last way without restructuring the table is to adjust the page geometry e.g. with `\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}`.

Comment: Could you please comment on the material difference(s), if any, between this question and the one you posted a few days ago (cf http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161562/5001)?

Comment: You should change the table layout to make it fit if it is too wide. This is the same across all editors and processors. You can adjust the inter-column padding as suggested in [Column and row padding in tables](http://goo.gl/X3kPH)...

Comment: ok, @Mico. but I don't know. can you help me.